# Azure DevOps pipeline auto-triggers in multiple pipelines unintentionally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, pipeline

I've been working on a cronjob pipeline that runs at x time of the day on the develop branch, but I've been running into an issue that has been problematic.

So for example, I have pipelines A, B and C. The pipeline that runs the cronjob should only trigger on pipeline A. Although this does work, it also triggers pipeline B in parallel which is completely unintended and not ideal as that pipeline's functionality is different.

Is there a way to configure the YAML file in a way so only pipeline A gets triggered and no other pipelines get triggered in the process?

Comment: A B & C are using the same yaml?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the pipelines and the repository/repositories? Are there multiple repositories used? One pipeline or more? On which branch they are stored?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk No they are all independent yaml files

Comment: @GeralexGR So all the pipelines are independent of each other but live in the same repository and in the develop branch. The repository it lives in holds all the infrastructure pipelines. The goal of the pipeline I am working on is to auto-delete resource groups at a certain time of the day (for cost savings especially with one of the resources). But when this pipeline does run, it seems to trigger other pipelines in parallel which have no remote connection to the other pipelines whatsoever as that pipeline only has the cronjob scheduling

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I would check will be the cron settings for other pipelines. If no YAML cron is defined I would go and check the GUI settings.

Press edit

[image]

and then triggers.

[image]

under scheduled you can locate if cron settings are defined on GUI.

[image]

Then you could also deactivate `pr` triggers and `branch` triggers for the pipelines that you do not want to get triggered as a second step of troubleshooting.